# SSIS Term Extraction for non-English text

Tags: sql-server-2008, data-mining, ssis

I started learning Data Mining with SQL Server and I was curious that SQL Server Integration Services is capable to perform Term Extraction from English text. However I'm interested to perform Text Mining from non-English text, basically from Ukrainian. So these are the very questions:

1. Is there a way to implement Term Extraction from non-English text in SSIS? If yes then any suitable resources would be appreciated:)
2. If the answer for the first question is positive I would like to know if there are already some custom solutions for non-English text.

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation [states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141809.aspx) that the term extraction transformation supports only English, and there's no mention of a mechanism for adding other languages.

Therefore, I would assume that you need to find some sort of tool that can do term extraction with Ukrainian text, and work out how to integrate it into SSIS. Finding a tool like that isn't really an SSIS issue, it's a general [NLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) or linguistics question, so you might get a better answer in another forum.